# PHP OAuth::fetch() returns bad request on second consecutive call

Tags: php, oauth

I am connecting to Smugmug API with OAuth1 and I have this code to retrieve Albums from their server.

```
class SmugmugHelper
{
    private $oauth_client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->oauth_client = new \OAuth("REPLACED_KEY", "KEPLACED_KEY");
        $this->oauth_client->setToken("REPLACED_KEY", "REPLACED_KEY");
    }

    public function getAlbum($node_id)
    {
        $url = "https://www.smugmug.com/api/v2/node/" . $node_id;
        $parameters = [];
        $method = 'GET';

        // this fetch always works
        $this->oauth_client->fetch($url, $parameters, $method, array('Accept' => 'application/json'));
        $response = $this->oauth_client->getLastResponse();
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        $album_uri = $response['Response']['Node']['Uris']['Album']['Uri'];
        $url = "https://www.smugmug.com" . $album_uri;

        // this fetch doesn't work on prod but it does on local
        $this->oauth_client->fetch($url, $parameters, $method, array('Accept' => 'application/json'));
        $response = $this->oauth_client->getLastResponse();
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        $album = $response['Response']['Album'];
        return $album;
    }
}
```

Then in my controller I do

```
$smmHelper = new SmugmugHelper();
$album = $smmHelper->getAlbum('FXzQcV');
```

Now, when I try to fetch the data from those ENDPOINTS, it works just fine in my local server but then in my prod server just the first fetch works, but then the second doesn't.

I tryied skipping the first fetch and hardcoding the same URL I get from the first one this way

```
...
// this fetch doesn't work on prod but it does on local
$this->oauth_client->fetch("Hardcoded URL", $parameters, $method, array('Accept' => 'application/json'));
...
```

And it works just doing one call.

I don't know what else to do.

My local server is an Apache2 with PHP Version 7.1.3 with OAuth extension enabled.

My production server is hosted by greengeeks.com and has a PHP Version 7.1 with OAuth extension enabled.

If there is any more information I could give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured this out. It was my prod server that had troubles with PHP v. 7.0 and OAuth extension v. 2.0.2.

I tried into another server with same PHP and extension versions and it worked like a charm.